Derive related generic struct from another struct
The title is pretty confusing, but I couldn't come up with a better one, sorry.
Imagine you have a trait that can be applied multiple times (through generics) to a struct:
    pub struct Model {}

    pub struct ModelCreateDto {}

    pub struct AnotherModel {}

    pub struct AnotherModelCreateDto {}


    pub trait SubModule<T> {
        fn create<D>(&self, data: D) -> Result<T, Error>;
    }


    impl SubModule<Model> for SomeStruct {
        pub async fn create(&self, data: ModelCreateDto) -> Result<Model, Error> {
            // ... create T from data
        }
    }

    impl SubModule<G> for SomeStruct {
        pub async fn create(&self, data: CreateDtoForG<G>) -> Result<AnotherModel, Error> {
            // ... create G from data
        }
    }

How can I a mark, for example, the ModelCreateDto struct as the creation dto for Model?
My goal is to be able to have the generic SubModule interface that enforces a strict type model.
So in other words: I want to mark D as "derived" from T in this part without having to declare D as generic parameter.
    pub trait SubModule<T> {
        fn create<D>(&self, data: D) -> Result<T, Error>;
    }

    // should be

    pub trait SubModule<T> {
        fn create(&self, data: D : derived from T) -> Result<T, Error>;
    }

I am not even sure if this makes sense. But I feel like it should be possible to infer the creation dto through the main model with some type/trait magic.
Cheers

T could be constrained to a trait with an associated type parameter: trait Foo { type Dto; } trait SubModule<T: Foo> { ... data: T::Dto ... } though it's unclear to me whether this is actually what you want...

@eggyal That seems like it could work. It is an unstable nightly feature though, correct?

What is?  Associated types?  No, not at all.  They have been stable since Rust v1.0

@eggyal Omg I just did it wrong apparently. This was exactly what I was looking for. If you add this as an answer I will accept it.
